# How to change sort order of generic properties in document types in Umbraco 4.7

Tags: asp.net, .net, umbraco

Is it possible to programatically sort properties on DocumentType? I am creating them from code, but not sure how to order them.

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how and what you want to sort, but here's an example of how you might sort them:

```
DocumentType dt = DocumentType.GetByAlias("umbTextpage");

//Get the one you want to move to the top.
var property = dt.PropertyTypes.First(p => p.Alias == "bodyText");

//Get the rest. Make sure you have the right TabId.
var otherProperties = dt.PropertyTypes.Where(p => p.Alias != "bodyText" && p.TabId == 8).ToList();

property.SortOrder = 0;
property.Save();

int i = 1;
foreach (var p in otherProperties)
{
    p.SortOrder = i++;
    p.Save();
}
```

Hopefully, that gives you some sort of starting place, if you haven't already figured it our already... The easiest way to get the TabId is to look at the cmsTab table in the database.

Answer (score -1):

Do you refer sorting based of the sub-pages of particular node? I mean your question little confuse...

anyway if you want to sort sub-pages; you can do that by something like following.

```
var eventsNode = @Model.NodeById(1058).orderbydesending("createddate");
```

Thanks,

Developerjigar

Comment: kranberg is asking about sorting the properties of a DocumentType, just as he said.